# WDDM vs DirectX vs Device Driver(say for Nvidia Card )?

Tags: graphics

I thought I knew what DX and Graphics card device driver meant. Today I was reading about Windows Display Driver Model(WDDM) and couldn't figure out what it does? It says WDDM is a Display driver model/architecture.

Does it mean it is a model/architecture that should be followed/implemented by the Graphics card manufacturer when writing a driver for their device so that the Windows OS display manager can use the device efficiently?

DirectX. on the other hand is the API(developed by Microsoft) that should be implemented/supported by the graphics cards and its drivers so that other software(not including the OS and its GUI components like display manager) like games can communicate with the Graphics Card using the API?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @user253751 What is WDDM? I am also trying to figure out if my understanding of it is correct and how it is similar/different compared to other systems like graphics APIs or Drivers.

Comment: "What is?" seems kinda broad

Comment: I suppose the explanation is that WDDM is the thing you have to implement to create a graphics driver on Windows.

Comment: @user253751 When you say 'implement' is it something specific like an API?..or is it like a guideline/checklist to create the driver? Sorry about the question being is broad!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/windows-vista-and-later-display-driver-model-architecture this diagram shows the 3 parts of a WDDM driver that you need to implement. If you look on the left there's a bunch of links about the DirectX user-mode and the display miniport parts. It doesn't show information about the OpenGL part but that's probably somewhere else. I think the target audience is people who already know how to write Windows drivers.